# Trie traversal in C and adding values to pointer array

Tags: c, arrays

I was working on a simple depth first traversal of a trie array.
The problem is, valgrind keeps giving me "use of uninitialized values of size 8" and "invalid writes to NULL" errors, before segfaulting; it fails on the line

```
     *newNodes[(*num)++] = trie->c;
```

and appears to fail right after it makes the first recursive call from the first layer.

Comment: Why this edit? You removed all the context. As it stands now, the question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that you are having issues with isn't being parsed how you think it is.  When you write `*newNodes[(*toKeep)++]`, the `C` compiler parses this as `*(newNodes[(*toKeep)++])`.  Based on your `realloc`, what you really want is

```
(*newNodes)[(*toKeep)++]
```

This will let you access the memory you just allocated.

Comment: I made the change, but it's still giving me the same errors:  Use of uninitialised value of size 8 EDIT: never mind, it works! thanks!